# JQuery Ajax: Total Likes not updating for post when pressing Like button

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

Two JQuery Ajax calls. First brings back user messages from MySQL, the number of likes for that message and a button for the user to like the message. This request is working.

Second Ajax request to fire from the user pressing the like button created from the first Ajax request. However, nothing appears to happen on pressing the button (no errors). Tried to view the results as an alert or in the console but nothing happened.

Ajax request 1:

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response) {

  $.each(response, function() {
      $.each($(this), function(i, item) {
      var mycss = (item.Type == 1) ? ' style="color: #ffa449;"' :'';
      $( '.content' ).append( '<div class="post"><div class="post-text"> ' +item.MessageText+ ' </div><div class="post-action"><input type="button" value="Like" id="like_'+item.ID+'_'+item.UserID+'" class="like" '+mycss+' /><span id="likes_'+item.ID+'_'+item.UserID+'">'+item.cntLikes+'</span></div></div>');

      });
  });
}
```

Example of the html produced:

```
<div class="post"><div class="post-text"> This is message example text. </div><div class="post-action"><input type="button" value="Like" id="like_1_f6khb11ldm2hek6bvs3qd2oef6" class="like"><span id="likes_1_f6khb11ldm2hek6bvs3qd2oef6">12</span></div></div>
```

Ajax request 2:

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
    var likes = data['likes'];
    var type = data['type'];

    $("#likes_" + postid + "_" + userid).text(likes);
    if(type == 1){
        $("#like_" + postid + "_" + userid).css("color","lightseagreen");
    }
    if(type == 0){
        $("#like_" + postid + "_" + userid).css("color","#ffa449"); 
    }
}
```

EDIT: On click second Ajax request code as requested:

```
$(".like").click(function(){
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typo: `$("#likes_" + postid + "_" + userid).text(likes);`. Should be `#like_`. Also, after using the suggestion below are you seeing a request sent?

Comment: @EternalHour thank you. So the span has likes and the button like class name. Or have I miss understood. I’ve tried the below but probably got the syntax wrong as it’s not working. The code I tried off the answer below is shown in the comments below that answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh I see, didn't notice that. Will you provide the outer HTML that you're modifying?

Comment: @EternalHour so there is a div with a class named “content” that wraps around all the messages and like buttons. Ie it’s static. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yeah. In that case `$(".content").on("click",".like",function(){}` should work. Are there multiple elements with the `.content` class?

Comment: Thank you @EternalHour, there aren’t multiple elements with the .content class. I have tried the syntax suggested but nothing happens. If there are multiple messages brought back each having the .like class how does the interpreter know, which like button to respond to? Out is interest. Thank you.

Comment: It knows because JQuery will automatically attach an event handler to all the child elements with the `like` class. You target the specific element that was clicked by using `$(this)`. But you don't appear to be targeting what is clicked you are trying to select them using a dynamically generated ID. You haven't provided enough context as to what your actual vs. expected result should be.

Comment: @EternalHour I've made the amendments suggested. Maybe there's an additional issue in the code. Anyway I'll keep on searching through this site to find an answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you can more thoroughly explain what you are expecting to happen someone may be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to echo the target? or just simple alert? if that not working it means the target is not sighted, this is specially when the elements are appended. so you need to have a static target

```
$("#static-target").on("click",".real-target",function(){
 //do here
});
```

Comment: Thank you. So I have the first Ajax request, which on success loops through the JSON array returned and creates an input button and some ids and classes for referencing. How does the appending of an additional ID as a static target help? Please can you advise? I'm a bit of a beginner still.

Comment: in your case i guessing that class .content is your static target and the success JSON that you iterate is the real target, not really id it can also be class as long as it is already there when your page first load happens

Comment: can you share your on click function? just need to change that one

Comment: Thank you. Will do once I get back home from work. :)

Comment: Have added in the requested code example. Gave your tip a go but couldn't get it to work. I'm obviously doing it wrong!

Comment: I tried $(".content").on("click",".like",function(), or should I point at the below dynamically some how... id="like_'+item.ID+'_'+item.UserID+'". Thank you again.

Comment: yes, you can use class .like and in order for you to distinguish the clicked from the other .like classes, you use $(this) instead of the dynamic id, can try $(this).css("color":"red") to try and see, as for getting specific values from it you can use data-model="set value here" and put the value there and take advantage of the .data("model") *this can be any word not limited t word model. to get and set a value for your further uses

Comment: you can also use value="" with .val() or id="" with .attr("id") to get specific data, though this is good, this is also bad. since your data will be seen in the DOM, thats why things like Vue.js came out to solve this issue