# JQuery Stop Text Flickering when Pressing Show Less / Show More

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a number of user stories on my website page. I don't want to show the entirety of each story if the user doesn't want to read it, so I show the first 2 lines and there is a Show more link to press to see the whole story. The user can then press the link again to See less. The issue comes when the user clicks the Show less link, the story condenses and shows 2 lines, but there is a momentary flicker of say 2 additional lines (can't quite make it out as its there for a few milliseconds). And it is this that I don't want.

This is my HTML and jQuery which is loaded via Ajax Request.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".content").on("click", ".showMore a", function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    var content = $this.parent().prev()
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();

    if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
      linkText = "Show less";
      content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);

    } else {
      linkText = "Show more";
      content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
    }

    $this.text(linkText);
  });

});
```

```css
.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 4em;
}

.showContent {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="content">
  <div class="hideContent" style="">
    <div class="post-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id erat pharetra risus fermentum aliquam. Maecenas eu nisi posuere, rutrum orci et, imperdiet elit. Nulla tempor imperdiet sagittis. Aenean cursus justo ac enim lacinia vehicula. Etiam dictum
      suscipit nibh, at iaculis velit lobortis vel. Duis pretium diam ut lectus mollis vehicula.</div>
    <div class="post-action"><input type="button" value="Like" id="like_94" class="like"><span class="likesTotal" id="likes_94">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="showMore"><a>Show more</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not understand what you re asking for . You want to hide the lines faster ?

Comment: @mark dibe sorry I don't want to see the flicker at all. The text hides back to 2 rows when clicking th see less link but there is this flicker, which is what I don't want. Thanks.

Comment: if youndo not want this flickering , you have to minimize the time needed to switch classes between show and hide put 10 instead of 400 content.switchClass('showContent','hideContent',10);

Comment: Ok thanks. Kind of defeats the point of using this method if you make the transition so quick. When pressing Show less the text is hidden all the way to 2 rows, which is what I want. It's then after that, a couple of sentences momentarily come onto the screen and then disappear. Are you sure its related to the switch class period?

Comment: What about other implementation ? Why dont you youse toggle instead. Try toggel its really fast and very good

Comment: I have spent some time looking at toggle. I have found that toggle is being used when something is completely hidden and then shown. In my situation I want to show the first 2 sentences and then show the rest of the text with a toggle, but I couldn't find any examples of this. Did you have any examples of this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that's what you wanted. You can do this easily by using `.addClass` and `.removeClass`

Also. if you content and stories display as exactly as the example in question then `.parent()` is not what you want you can call `.prev()` and it will work just find.

Simple Show and Hide

Using `addClass` and `removeClass`

Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/cks8d067/

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".showMore").on("click", function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    var content = $this.prev()
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();

    if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
      linkText = "Show less";
      content.addClass("showContent").removeClass("hideContent");
    } else {
      content.addClass("hideContent").removeClass("showContent");
      linkText = "Show more";
    }

    $this.text(linkText);
  });

});
```

```css
.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: auto;
}
.showMore {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hideContent">
  <div class="post-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id erat pharetra risus fermentum aliquam. Maecenas eu nisi posuere, rutrum orci et, imperdiet elit. Nulla tempor imperdiet sagittis. Aenean cursus justo ac enim lacinia vehicula. Etiam dictum
    suscipit nibh, at iaculis velit lobortis vel. Duis pretium diam ut lectus mollis vehicula.</div>
  <div class="post-action"><input type="button" value="Like" id="like_94" class="like"><span class="likesTotal" id="likes_94">0</span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="showMore"><a>Show more</a></div>
```

**Accordion Effects**

Using accordion effect we can use `.animate` and `.css`

To do the accordion effects we can use .animate and .css for height to show more or less of the story. We will use `.siblings`

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/ovgah34z/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".content").on("click", '.showMore', function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    var content = $this.prev()
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();

    if (linkText === "SHOW MORE") {
      linkText = "Show less";
      $this.siblings('div').css('height', 'auto');
      var currHeight = $this.siblings('div').height();
      $this.siblings('div').css('height', '2em');
      $this.siblings('div').animate({
        height: currHeight
      }, 500);
    } else {
      $this.siblings('div').animate({
        height: '2em'
      }, 500);
      linkText = "Show more";
    }

    $this.text(linkText);
  });

});
```

```css
.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: auto;
}

.showMore {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="hideContent">
    <div class="post-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In id erat pharetra risus fermentum aliquam. Maecenas eu nisi posuere, rutrum orci et, imperdiet elit. Nulla tempor imperdiet sagittis. Aenean cursus justo ac enim lacinia vehicula. Etiam dictum
      suscipit nibh, at iaculis velit lobortis vel. Duis pretium diam ut lectus mollis vehicula.</div>
    <div class="post-action"><input type="button" value="Like" id="like_94" class="like"><span class="likesTotal" id="likes_94">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="showMore"><a>Show more</a></div>

</div>
```

Let me know.

Comment: Thank you. So the code I have seems to work ok. It's on pressing the show less link that it flickers a couple of lines for a millisecond when all but the last 2 rows are hidden (can't see what these rogue lines say). I don't want that flicker and would like to know why it is happening. Happy to accept a better alternative approach, but would still like the slow accordion effect. Also I accepted an edit on my question and they added in the Bootstrap link. Do I need that? I don't use Bootstrap.

Comment: @CGarden You can edit the question the back to remove the bootstrap link if you are not using bootstrap. The solution i gave is without bootstrap as well and is working fine. I do not see any flicker (as you say) when i press on show more or show less. Its all working fine. Could you please show us you website if you can so i can this flicker issue you are mentioning.

Comment: I don't currently have this incorporated into my site. It's on a test server. But I can look to add it to show if the above doesn't work. How would I apply the accordion effect? Thanks.

Comment: @CGarden You can incorporate accordian effect by using `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`

Comment: Thank you. So I create the html using an Ajax request which pulls the stories from a MySql database. The Content class is the element that is there before firing the Ajax request when the document loads, that is why I navigate from this to fire the Show more or less link. Also if I take out the .parent() neither my code or your code works. I have added in the slideUp and slideDown. slideUp syntax: `content.addClass("hideContent").removeClass("showContent").slideUp(400);`. The slide down works fine but the slide up is hiding everything. Clearly doing this wrong! Could you advise please.

Comment: @CGarden I have edited my answer with two methods you wanted. Both are working as you wanted. One method is with simple using `addclass` and `removeClass`. The other method you wanted was accordion effect on the stories show more or less. That's working as well. Can you please accept my answer as the solution i have addressed both issues. Thank You.

Comment: both methods are great, and its good that you have provided multiple options for the OP to choose whichever fits him best

Comment: Sorry I just wanted to say thank you. But its worth stating that my question was about using the accordion effect. So your initial answer was not relevant to that. The second piece of code you have posted I can't get to work. As mentioned in my question Ajax is used to create the original html under the 'Content' div, hence I'm navigating from that point using jQuery and thats why your code is not working for me. This is my selector `$(".content").on("click",".showMore a",`. I'm trying to amend your code to get it to work, and even then it may not have solved the issue. Thank you though.

Comment: @CGarden Your original question was NOT about accordion effect its about having flickering issue and you wanted to avoid that. Hence why i suggested and provided two working solutions as i said it up-to you choose what you like the most. I am aware that you load stories via ajax. You do NOT need to use your selector like this `$(".content").on("click",".showMore a",` use this code from my WORKING js fiddle with effect as you wanted [here](https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/cks8d067/)

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. If you look at my code you can see there is a transition time of hiding the paragraph, so that is the accordion effect. If I didn't want to see the flicker I could have just decreased the time input. But this could have been clearer. Apologies. As regards a selector, all I know is that I can only get your code to work while using 'content'. Would you be able to tell me why my original code isn't right. And how yours works. As you can tell I still have a lot to learn. Apologies for my last message. I just don't know why I can't get your code to work. Thank you.

Comment: @CGarden No worries :) It will be hard to know why the code is not working on your actual website - as you know there could be multiple factors which i will not know until i see it. I provided you two complete reproducible WORKING examples as above. I have added a js Fiddle for you as well. My example are working there as well as here.

Comment: Thanks. What's the principal behind how the siblings work in your example? What are you doing there? I'm interested.

Comment: @CGarden The way `siblings` works is that when you click on show on `.showMore` its check it will check its siblings which  are two `divs` its get only first div which is hideContent and applies animation on that one and again when its show less is clicked its checks again reverses the animation. You can also read more about `.siblings` [here on jQuery official](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Thank you. That's really great. I was looking at my previous questions and I use the syntax logic like this example "$(".content").on("click",".showMore a" due to this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707409/jquery-ajax-total-likes-not-updating-for-post-when-pressing-like-button) Does that make any sense? Thanks.

Comment: @CGarden Using that here will not work as we do NOT have  `.content` in the above HTML in or in your original question. This `$(".content").on("click",".showMore a", ` will WORK only if there actual hideContent and show more in wrapped inside `.content` div. Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/cks8d067/

Comment: That's right there is a content div that wraps it all. My fault I eluded to this but did not explicitly add to the question. Sorry!

Comment: @CGarden No worries! Glad to hear that. I hope i have cleared all your queries and have explained in details with working examples. Would you mind accepting my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of toggle inside a custom function .
If this is the result that you want .
Do not forget to mark my answer as the right answer!
Regards

```js
 
        function makeTheMagic(){
    $("#extraContent").toggle();
    let btnText=  $("#btnAction").text() == "Show More!"?"Show Less!":"Show More!";
    $("#btnAction").text(btnText);
}
```

```html
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='card'>
        <div class='card-body'>
            <p class='alert-success'>
               In my situation I want to show the first 2 sentences and then show the rest of the text with a toggle, but I couldn't find any examples of this. Did you have any examples of this? Thank you. 
            </p>
            <p class='alert-danger' style='display:none' id='extraContent'>
                I have a number of user stories on my website page. I don't want to show the entirety of each story if the user doesn't want to read it, so I show the first 2 lines and there is a Show more link to press to see the whole story. The user can then press the link again to See less. The issue comes when the user clicks the Show less link, the story condenses and shows 2 lines, but there is a momentary flicker of say 2 additional lines (can't quite make it out as its there for a few milliseconds). And it is this that I don't want.
            </p>
            <span class='btn btn-outline-success' onclick='makeTheMagic()' id='btnAction'>Show More!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. The stories are extracted from a MySQL database using an Ajax request. So that's why splitting the text out into 2 <p> tags isn't what I'm looking for.